# Llamar a la clave foranea PHP

Tags: php, formularios

Estoy intentado hacer un formulario despues de hacer un login como usuario y en la base de datos tengo una llave foranea que es usuario_id de la tabla pedidos que se junta con id_usuario de la tabla usuarios

Este codigo es el que almacenaria el pedido pero me faltaria agregar el usuario_id para que aparezca que id del usaurio que solicito el pedido en la tabla de pedidos pero no sabria como agregarlo

```
    <?php
        include("../conexion.php");
        session_start();
        if(empty($_SESSION['active'])){
            header('location: ../login.php');
        }
        ?>

  <form method="post" action="insertarp.php">
   <div class="input-group">
  <!--  <input type="hidden" name="u_id" value="<?php// echo $_SESSION['usuario_id']; ?>"> -->
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
    <label>Tipo de servicio</label>
            <select name="tipox" id="user_type" >
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>

    <label>Tipo</label>
            <select name="carx" id="user_type" >
                <option value="1">S/C</option>
                <option value="2">G</option>
                <option value="3">M</option>

            </select>

    <label>Fecha del servicio</label>
    <input type="date" name="fechax">

    <label>Telefono</label>
    <input type="number" name="telx">

    <label>Mensajes/Comentarios</label>
    <input type="text" name="menx" placeholder="Sin comentarios">

    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="btn">Solicitar</button>
        </div>
 
    </form>
```

> Esto es donde se insertan los datos del formulario anterior insertarp.php

```
<?php
include("../conexion.php");

$tipo = $_POST["tipox"];
$car = $_POST["carx"];
$fecha = $_POST["fechax"];
$tel = $_POST["telx"];
$mensaje = $_POST["menx"];

$us_id = $_POST["u_id"];

//var_dump($_POST);

$actualizar2 = "INSERT INTO pedidos (tipo_ser,car,fecha,c_tel,men,usuario_id) VALUES ('$tipo','$car', '$fecha', '$tel', '$mensaje', '$us_id' )";

$resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $actualizar2);

if($resultado2){
    echo "<script> alert('Haz solicitado el servicio');
    window.location='index.php'</script>"; 
    
}else{
   //echo "<script>alert('Error.. Al solicitar cita....'); window.history.go(1); </script>"; 
}
```

> Cualquier duda de el codigo comenten y edito

Comment: en el archivo de login.php estas guardando el `usuario_id` en la session? sino, aunque descomentes el input hidden no te llegara tampoco...

Comment: En el login del usuario guardo la llave foranea de la otra tabla? Creo que la id desaparece cuando intento mostrarlo con: <?php echo $_SESSION['id_u']; ?> En el login del usuario guardo: 
            $_SESSION['active'] = true;
            $_SESSION['id_u'] = $data['id'];
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $data['usuario'];
            $_SESSION['nombre'] = $data['nombre'];

Comment: Revisa los nombres que guardas. En el formulario de insertar pedidos tienes comentado el campo `u_id`, y pones un PHP para ver el sesión de `usuario_id`. Con lo cual nunca va a llegar al post el campo. No haces referencia a ningún `id_u` que parece ser el que guarda el id de usuario... Intenta poner los mismos nombres